# Multiresolution bug in blender 2.8

Tags: sculpting, multiresolution

Using multiresolution modifier and subdividing causes "wrinkles" to appear

[image: Example]

[My .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RTkMQZdhkuTILYPIbmTpDpFzQNViMRiD)

Comment: It is a fundamental flaw in how multiresolution in Blender works and is implemented. The next division is always relative to the previous and resolutions are not re-computed when you do changes (they are not updated to work in tangent space). Does not work like in Zbrush. If you do changes in lower resolution, you mess up your higher resolutions, because you change their base. A one of many deal breakers of Blender sculpting for me too.

Comment: I don't change lower resolution layers. I sculpt at lvl 1, then subdivide (first time) to lvl 2 and this appears. Clicking "apply base" fixes the problem (just found out), but that wasn't necessary in blender 2.79